# How to convert thunderbird inbox file to eml

Tags: email, data-recovery, thunderbird

I got a bare **Inbox** file (that without any extension) from thunferbird that was copied from another machine. I do not have any info about account; only a few more **.msf** files. I need a way to convert the file to separate **eml** files. How would i do this?

Comment: do you mean inbox file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mailbox is in the `Inbox` file, using the [*mboxrd*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox) format. The format is very simple; all messages are simply concatenated together, with `From_` headers added and with existing such lines in the body escaped.

The `Inbox` file can be given to any "mbox to eml" or "mbox to Maildir" conversion tool, or even to a simple script that splits upon `/^From /` lines.

Randomly-accessing a *mbox* mailbox can be very slow when it grows large, so `Inbox.msf` is a ["summary" of the mailbox](http://www.jwz.org/doc/mailsum.html) in the [Mork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mork_%28file_format%29) format (which is not much faster).

The `.msf` files are only useful to Thunderbird and can be discarded otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

did you try [mbox2eml](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mbox2eml/)? There is also other utility from different author with the same name [here](http://www.broobles.com/imapsize/mbox2eml.php).

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows 10 I've successfully used:

- the old [IMAPSize](https://www.broobles.com/imapsize/)
- the old [UKrebs mbox2eml](http://ukrebs-software.de/german/mbox2eml/mbox2eml.html) Java Programm

to convert a thunderbird mbox-file into eml-files.

**IMAPSize** main usage is with IMAP-Servers. But the conversion tools *won't* need a IMAP-Server. It says it's able to work with big files. I haven't testet that though.

**UKreb's mbox2eml** will load the mbox file into memory and will thus be limited to how much RAM you're machine has. Be aware that you will need to start Java with `java -Xmx256m -jar mbox2eml.jar` to allow it to use more memory.

Event though it is written in Java, *it won't run under Linux*. As an upside: the sourcecode is available.